# Not able to Pass customer_id Value in the form to a partial as hidden field value in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2, partials

I have this in the Main form

```
    <%= simple_nested_form_for @customer_bill do |f| %>

        <%= f.label :customer_id %>
        <%= f.collection_select :customer_id, Customer.all,:id,:name, {:prompt => "Select Customer"}, :style => 'width:205px;' %><br />

        <%= f.link_to_add "Add", :customer_bill_line_items,  :locals => {:text_1 => :customer_id} %>
    /* rest of code */
    <%end%>
```

And i have this in my customer_bill_line_items Partial

```
<%= f.hidden_field :customer_id, :value => :text_1 %>
/*rest of code*/
```

But i am not Able to capture the selected customer id in the partial. The value of hidden field is coming as 0. Any guidance on  how i can solve this matter will be great. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<%= f.hidden_field :customer_id, :value => :text_1 %>
```

I am guessing that customer_id in an integer field, and you are setting the :value as text_1 which is a string.

if the value of text_1 is an integer then text_1.to_i